# make regex mark only completed words

Tags: regex

i make regex that replace all first domain's except one.
But proble is there that its mark not completed words .co (not completed) instead .com (completed).

here is a demo https://regex101.com/r/uO4uT5/2

any solution?

Comment: To be honest, I do not understand what you're trying to achieve, could you repeat it in plain English? For starters, please post your code and **desired output** here. Second, which language/editor are you using?

Comment: In what way is .co not completed? It's the tld for Colombia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`

```
^domain\.com$(*SKIP)(*F)|http:\/\/|https:\/\/|\.(?:AAA|AARP|ABB|ABBOTT|ABOGADO|AC|ACADEMY|ACCENTURE|ACCOUNTANT|ACCOUNTANTS|ACO|ACTIVE|ACTOR|AD|ADAC|ADS|ADULT|AE|AEG|AERO|AF|AFL|AG|AGENCY|AI|AIG|AIRFORCE|AIRTEL|AL|ALIBABA|ALIPAY|ALLFINANZ|ALSACE|AM|AMICA|AMSTERDAM|ANALYTICS|ANDROID|AO|APARTMENTS|APP|APPLE|AQ|AQUARELLE|AR|ARAMCO|ARCHI|ARMY|ARPA|ARTE|AS|ASIA|ASSOCIATES|AT|ATTORNEY|AU|AUCTION|AUDI|AUDIO|AUTHOR|AUTO|AUTOS|AW|AX|AXA|AZ|AZURE|BA|BAIDU|BAND|BANK|BAR|BARCELONA|BARCLAYCARD|BARCLAYS|BARGAINS|BAUHAUS|BAYERN|BB|BBC|BBVA|BCN|BD|BE|BEATS|BEER|BENTLEY|BERLIN|BEST|BET|BF|BG|BH|BHARTI|BI|BIBLE|BID|BIKE|BING|BINGO|BIO|BIZ|BJ|BLACK|BLACKFRIDAY|BLOOMBERG|BLUE|BM|BMS|BMW|BN|BNL|BNPPARIBAS|BO|BOATS|BOEHRINGER|BOM|BOND|BOO|BOOK|BOOTS|BOSCH|BOSTIK|BOT|BOUTIQUE|BR|BRADESCO|BRIDGESTONE|BROADWAY|BROKER|BROTHER|BRUSSELS|BS|BT|BUDAPEST|BUGATTI|BUILD|BUILDERS|BUSINESS|BUY|BUZZ|BV|BW|BY|BZ|BZH|CA|CAB|CAFE|CAL|CALL|CAMERA|CAMP|CANCERRESEARCH|CANON|CAPETOWN|CAPITAL|CAR|CARAVAN|CARDS|CARE|CAREER|CAREERS|CARS|CARTIER|CASA|CASH|CASINO|CAT|CATERING|CBA|CBN|CC|CD|CEB|CENTER|CEO|CERN|CF|CFA|CFD|CG|CH|CHANEL|CHANNEL|CHAT|CHEAP|CHLOE|CHRISTMAS|CHROME|CHURCH|CI|CIPRIANI|CIRCLE|CISCO|CITIC|CITY|CITYEATS|CK|CL|CLAIMS|CLEANING|CLICK|CLINIC|CLINIQUE|CLOTHING|CLOUD|CLUB|CLUBMED|CM|CN|CO|COACH|CODES|COFFEE|COLLEGE|COLOGNE|COM|COMMBANK|COMMUNITY|COMPANY|COMPARE|COMPUTER|COMSEC|CONDOS|CONSTRUCTION|CONSULTING|CONTACT|CONTRACTORS|COOKING|COOL|COOP|CORSICA|COUNTRY|COUPON|COUPONS|COURSES|CR|CREDIT|CREDITCARD|CREDITUNION|CRICKET|CROWN|CRS|CRUISES|CSC|CU|CUISINELLA|CV|CW|CX|CY|CYMRU|CYOU|CZ|DABUR|DAD|DANCE|DATE|DATING|DATSUN|DAY|DCLK|DE|DEALER|DEALS|DEGREE|DELIVERY|DELL|DELOITTE|DELTA|DEMOCRAT|DENTAL|DENTIST|DESI|DESIGN|DEV|DIAMONDS|DIET|DIGITAL|DIRECT|DIRECTORY|DISCOUNT|DJ|DK|DM|DNP|DO|DOCS|DOG|DOHA|DOMAINS|DOOSAN|DOWNLOAD|DRIVE|DUBAI|DURBAN|DVAG|DZ|EARTH|EAT|EC|EDEKA|EDU|EDUCATION|EE|EG|EMAIL|EMERCK|ENERGY|ENGINEER|ENGINEERING|ENTERPRISES|EPSON|EQUIPMENT|ER|ERNI|ES|ESQ|ESTATE|ET|EU|EUROVISION|EUS|EVENTS|EVERBANK|EXCHANGE|EXPERT|EXPOSED|EXPRESS|FAGE|FAIL|FAIRWINDS|FAITH|FAMILY|FAN|FANS|FARM|FASHION|FAST|FEEDBACK|FERRERO|FI|FILM|FINAL|FINANCE|FINANCIAL|FIRESTONE|FIRMDALE|FISH|FISHING|FIT|FITNESS|FJ|FK|FLICKR|FLIGHTS|FLORIST|FLOWERS|FLSMIDTH|FLY|FM|FO|FOO|FOOTBALL|FORD|FOREX|FORSALE|FORUM|FOUNDATION|FOX|FR|FRESENIUS|FRL|FROGANS|FRONTIER|FUND|FURNITURE|FUTBOL|FYI|GA|GAL|GALLERY|GALLUP|GAME|GARDEN|GB|GBIZ|GD|GDN|GE|GEA|GENT|GENTING|GF|GG|GGEE|GH|GI|GIFT|GIFTS|GIVES|GIVING|GL|GLASS|GLE|GLOBAL|GLOBO|GM|GMAIL|GMO|GMX|GN|GOLD|GOLDPOINT|GOLF|GOO|GOOG|GOOGLE|GOP|GOT|GOV|GP|GQ|GR|GRAINGER|GRAPHICS|GRATIS|GREEN|GRIPE|GROUP|GS|GT|GU|GUCCI|GUGE|GUIDE|GUITARS|GURU|GW|GY|HAMBURG|HANGOUT|HAUS|HDFCBANK|HEALTH|HEALTHCARE|HELP|HELSINKI|HERE|HERMES|HIPHOP|HITACHI|HIV|HK|HM|HN|HOCKEY|HOLDINGS|HOLIDAY|HOMEDEPOT|HOMES|HONDA|HORSE|HOST|HOSTING|HOTELES|HOTMAIL|HOUSE|HOW|HR|HSBC|HT|HU|HYUNDAI|IBM|ICBC|ICE|ICU|ID|IE|IFM|IINET|IL|IM|IMMO|IMMOBILIEN|IN|INDUSTRIES|INFINITI|INFO|ING|INK|INSTITUTE|INSURANCE|INSURE|INT|INTERNATIONAL|INVESTMENTS|IO|IPIRANGA|IQ|IR|IRISH|IS|ISELECT|IST|ISTANBUL|IT|ITAU|IWC|JAGUAR|JAVA|JCB|JE|JETZT|JEWELRY|JLC|JLL|JM|JMP|JO|JOBS|JOBURG|JOT|JOY|JP|JPRS|JUEGOS|KAUFEN|KDDI|KE|KFH|KG|KH|KI|KIA|KIM|KINDER|KITCHEN|KIWI|KM|KN|KOELN|KOMATSU|KP|KPN|KR|KRD|KRED|KW|KY|KYOTO|KZ|LA|LACAIXA|LAMBORGHINI|LAMER|LANCASTER|LAND|LANDROVER|LANXESS|LASALLE|LAT|LATROBE|LAW|LAWYER|LB|LC|LDS|LEASE|LECLERC|LEGAL|LEXUS|LGBT|LI|LIAISON|LIDL|LIFE|LIFEINSURANCE|LIFESTYLE|LIGHTING|LIKE|LIMITED|LIMO|LINCOLN|LINDE|LINK|LIVE|LIVING|LIXIL|LK|LOAN|LOANS|LOL|LONDON|LOTTE|LOTTO|LOVE|LR|LS|LT|LTD|LTDA|LU|LUPIN|LUXE|LUXURY|LV|LY|MA|MADRID|MAIF|MAISON|MAKEUP|MAN|MANAGEMENT|MANGO|MARKET|MARKETING|MARKETS|MARRIOTT|MBA|MC|MD|ME|MED|MEDIA|MEET|MELBOURNE|MEME|MEMORIAL|MEN|MENU|MEO|MG|MH|MIAMI|MICROSOFT|MIL|MINI|MK|ML|MM|MMA|MN|MO|MOBI|MOBILY|MODA|MOE|MOI|MOM|MONASH|MONEY|MONTBLANC|MORMON|MORTGAGE|MOSCOW|MOTORCYCLES|MOV|MOVIE|MOVISTAR|MP|MQ|MR|MS|MT|MTN|MTPC|MTR|MU|MUSEUM|MUTUELLE|MV|MW|MX|MY|MZ|NA|NADEX|NAGOYA|NAME|NATURA|NAVY|NC|NE|NEC|NET|NETBANK|NETWORK|NEUSTAR|NEW|NEWS|NEXUS|NF|NG|NGO|NHK|NI|NICO|NIKON|NINJA|NISSAN|NL|NO|NOKIA|NORTON|NOWRUZ|NP|NR|NRA|NRW|NTT|NU|NYC|NZ|OBI|OFFICE|OKINAWA|OM|OMEGA|ONE|ONG|ONL|ONLINE|OOO|ORACLE|ORANGE|ORG|ORGANIC|ORIGINS|OSAKA|OTSUKA|OVH|PA|PAGE|PAMPEREDCHEF|PANERAI|PARIS|PARS|PARTNERS|PARTS|PARTY|PE|PET|PF|PG|PH|PHARMACY|PHILIPS|PHOTO|PHOTOGRAPHY|PHOTOS|PHYSIO|PIAGET|PICS|PICTET|PICTURES|PID|PIN|PING|PINK|PIZZA|PK|PL|PLACE|PLAY|PLAYSTATION|PLUMBING|PLUS|PM|PN|POHL|POKER|PORN|POST|PR|PRAXI|PRESS|PRO|PROD|PRODUCTIONS|PROF|PROMO|PROPERTIES|PROPERTY|PROTECTION|PS|PT|PUB|PW|PWC|PY|QA|QPON|QUEBEC|QUEST|RACING|RE|READ|REALTOR|REALTY|RECIPES|RED|REDSTONE|REDUMBRELLA|REHAB|REISE|REISEN|REIT|REN|RENT|RENTALS|REPAIR|REPORT|REPUBLICAN|REST|RESTAURANT|REVIEW|REVIEWS|REXROTH|RICH|RICOH|RIO|RIP|RO|ROCHER|ROCKS|RODEO|ROOM|RS|RSVP|RU|RUHR|RUN|RW|RWE|RYUKYU|SA|SAARLAND|SAFE|SAFETY|SAKURA|SALE|SALON|SAMSUNG|SANDVIK|SANDVIKCOROMANT|SANOFI|SAP|SAPO|SARL|SAS|SAXO|SB|SBS|SC|SCA|SCB|SCHAEFFLER|SCHMIDT|SCHOLARSHIPS|SCHOOL|SCHULE|SCHWARZ|SCIENCE|SCOR|SCOT|SD|SE|SEAT|SECURITY|SEEK|SELECT|SENER|SERVICES|SEVEN|SEW|SEX|SEXY|SFR|SG|SH|SHARP|SHELL|SHIA|SHIKSHA|SHOES|SHOW|SHRIRAM|SI|SINGLES|SITE|SJ|SK|SKI|SKIN|SKY|SKYPE|SL|SM|SMILE|SN|SNCF|SO|SOCCER|SOCIAL|SOFTBANK|SOFTWARE|SOHU|SOLAR|SOLUTIONS|SONY|SOY|SPACE|SPIEGEL|SPOT|SPREADBETTING|SR|SRL|ST|STADA|STAR|STARHUB|STATEFARM|STATOIL|STC|STCGROUP|STOCKHOLM|STORAGE|STUDIO|STUDY|STYLE|SU|SUCKS|SUPPLIES|SUPPLY|SUPPORT|SURF|SURGERY|SUZUKI|SV|SWATCH|SWISS|SX|SY|SYDNEY|SYMANTEC|SYSTEMS|SZ|TAB|TAIPEI|TAOBAO|TATAMOTORS|TATAR|TATTOO|TAX|TAXI|TC|TCI|TD|TEAM|TECH|TECHNOLOGY|TEL|TELEFONICA|TEMASEK|TENNIS|TF|TG|TH|THD|THEATER|THEATRE|TICKETS|TIENDA|TIFFANY|TIPS|TIRES|TIROL|TJ|TK|TL|TM|TMALL|TN|TO|TODAY|TOKYO|TOOLS|TOP|TORAY|TOSHIBA|TOURS|TOWN|TOYOTA|TOYS|TR|TRADE|TRADING|TRAINING|TRAVEL|TRAVELERS|TRAVELERSINSURANCE|TRUST|TRV|TT|TUBE|TUI|TUSHU|TV|TVS|TW|TZ|UA|UBS|UG|UK|UNICOM|UNIVERSITY|UNO|UOL|US|UY|UZ|VA|VACATIONS|VANA|VC|VE|VEGAS|VENTURES|VERISIGN|VERSICHERUNG|VET|VG|VI|VIAJES|VIDEO|VILLAS|VIN|VIP|VIRGIN|VISION|VISTA|VISTAPRINT|VIVA|VLAANDEREN|VN|VODKA|VOLKSWAGEN|VOTE|VOTING|VOTO|VOYAGE|VU|WALES|WALTER|WANG|WANGGOU|WATCH|WATCHES|WEATHER|WEATHERCHANNEL|WEBCAM|WEBER|WEBSITE|WED|WEDDING|WEIR|WF|WHOSWHO|WIEN|WIKI|WILLIAMHILL|WIN|WINDOWS|WINE|WME|WOLTERSKLUWER|WORK|WORKS|WORLD|WS|WTC|WTF|XBOX|XEROX|XIN|XN--11B4C3D|XN--1CK2E1B|XN--1QQW23A|XN--30RR7Y|XN--3BST00M|XN--3DS443G|XN--3E0B707E|XN--3PXU8K|XN--42C2D9A|XN--45BRJ9C|XN--45Q11C|XN--4GBRIM|XN--55QW42G|XN--55QX5D|XN--6FRZ82G|XN--6QQ986B3XL|XN--80ADXHKS|XN--80AO21A|XN--80ASEHDB|XN--80ASWG|XN--8Y0A063A|XN--90A3AC|XN--90AIS|XN--9DBQ2A|XN--9ET52U|XN--B4W605FERD|XN--BCK1B9A5DRE4C|XN--C1AVG|XN--C2BR7G|XN--CCK2B3B|XN--CG4BKI|XN--CLCHC0EA0B2G2A9GCD|XN--CZR694B|XN--CZRS0T|XN--CZRU2D|XN--D1ACJ3B|XN--D1ALF|XN--E1A4C|XN--ECKVDTC9D|XN--EFVY88H|XN--ESTV75G|XN--FHBEI|XN--FIQ228C5HS|XN--FIQ64B|XN--FIQS8S|XN--FIQZ9S|XN--FJQ720A|XN--FLW351E|XN--FPCRJ9C3D|XN--FZC2C9E2C|XN--G2XX48C|XN--GCKR3F0F|XN--GECRJ9C|XN--H2BRJ9C|XN--HXT814E|XN--I1B6B1A6A2E|XN--IMR513N|XN--IO0A7I|XN--J1AEF|XN--J1AMH|XN--J6W193G|XN--JLQ61U9W7B|XN--KCRX77D1X4A|XN--KPRW13D|XN--KPRY57D|XN--KPU716F|XN--KPUT3I|XN--L1ACC|XN--LGBBAT1AD8J|XN--MGB9AWBF|XN--MGBA3A3EJT|XN--MGBA3A4F16A|XN--MGBAAM7A8H|XN--MGBAB2BD|XN--MGBAYH7GPA|XN--MGBB9FBPOB|XN--MGBBH1A71E|XN--MGBC0A9AZCG|XN--MGBERP4A5D4AR|XN--MGBPL2FH|XN--MGBT3DHD|XN--MGBTX2B|XN--MGBX4CD0AB|XN--MIX891F|XN--MK1BU44C|XN--MXTQ1M|XN--NGBC5AZD|XN--NGBE9E0A|XN--NODE|XN--NQV7F|XN--NQV7FS00EMA|XN--NYQY26A|XN--O3CW4H|XN--OGBPF8FL|XN--P1ACF|XN--P1AI|XN--PBT977C|XN--PGBS0DH|XN--PSSY2U|XN--Q9JYB4C|XN--QCKA1PMC|XN--QXAM|XN--RHQV96G|XN--ROVU88B|XN--S9BRJ9C|XN--SES554G|XN--T60B56A|XN--TCKWE|XN--UNUP4Y|XN--VERMGENSBERATER-CTB|XN--VERMGENSBERATUNG-PWB|XN--VHQUV|XN--VUQ861B|XN--WGBH1C|XN--WGBL6A|XN--XHQ521B|XN--XKC2AL3HYE2A|XN--XKC2DL3A5EE0H|XN--Y9A3AQ|XN--YFRO4I67O|XN--YGBI2AMMX|XN--ZFR164B|XPERIA|XXX|XYZ|YACHTS|YAHOO|YAMAXUN|YANDEX|YE|YODOBASHI|YOGA|YOKOHAMA|YOUTUBE|YT|ZA|ZARA|ZERO|ZIP|ZM|ZONE|ZUERICH|ZW)\b
```

[See your updated demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iG1bS1/1)